# bitnami gitlab 8.1.4-0 gitl clone via http error :empty repo and download zip via webpage error

Tags: gitlab, bitnami, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-7

**gitlab version: bitnami gitlab-8.1.4_x64**

**os: ubuntu 12.04_x64**

Just the title, I setup a repo on gitlab and **push code via ssh is ok**, but when i try to **clone via http I get an empty repository.**
I have tried to add nginx item in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb but it didn't work. Anyone can give me some help? Thank you so much!

```
nginx['enabled'] = false
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_addr'] = "localhost:80"
```

At the same time, I will get following information if I try to **download a zip from webpage.**

```
{"RepoPath":"/opt/gitlab-8.1.4-0/apps/gitlab/repositories/wy/demo.git","ArchivePrefix":"demo-master-15fa55ea4cbd9a1368b2de6cda77b457e85f1573","ArchivePath":"/opt/gitlab-8.1.4-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/tmp/repositories/demo.git/demo-master-15fa55ea4cbd9a1368b2de6cda77b457e85f1573.zip","CommitId":"15fa55ea4cbd9a1368b2de6cda77b457e85f1573"}
```

When using **gitlab-ci-multi-runner** I will get the proble with

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.6.0 (4d8b5c2)
Using Shell executor...
Running on common...

Cloning repository...
Cloning into 'builds/e26b4ecf/0/wy/demo'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking out 15fa55ea as master...
fatal: reference is not a tree: 15fa55ea4cbd9a1368b2de6cda77b457e85f1573

ERROR: Build failed with: exit status 1
```

Comment: push code using `git remote add origin git@your_git_project.git` and
`git push origin master`

Comment: yes, push or clone via ssh is ok, but if I set origin as http://xxxx.git it dose not work. At the same time download source as a zip file on web page failed. @ Ashraful Islam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not your fault, it is a bug in Bitnami packaging. So far there is no  official solution but you can [implement some workarounds as seen here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/http-cannot-access-repository-for-push/38085/3). You can go using SSH, but I would wait for a decent patch.

## Update:

[Bitnami now offers Gitlab 8.2.3-3](https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab). This solves the problems.

Comment: Yes, I have turn back to an old version.

Comment: Is there anything else I can help, or add? useful accepted answers are good for the community.